# mongoose - how to populate from parent to child document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm just start to learn mongoose, I have 3 collections (User, Post, Comment), with their schema like this:

`User`

```
{
  fullName: String,
  email: String,
}
```

`Post`

```
{
  author: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User'},
  description: String
  //other property not really usefull
}
```

`Comment`

```
{
  postId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Post'},
  comment: [
    {
      user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User',
      },
      value: String,
      created: {type: Date, default: new Date().toISOString()},
    },
  ],
}
```

I want to fetch `post` detail `_id` with `comment` and detail of `user` `comment` and the result i'm expected is something like this:

```
{
  "author": "65a24698a247a52009fb97af",
  "description": "I'm the descriptor",
  "comments": [
    {
      "postId": "65abb2cbacb4458e1be4f18b",
      "comment": [
        {
          "created": "2024-01-20T13:28:26.807Z",
          "user": { "fullName": "Flix", "email": "flixy121@gmail.com" },
          "value": "Comment gw nih 123"
        },
        {
          "created": "2024-01-20T13:28:26.807Z",
          "user": { "fullName": "Flix", "email": "flixy121@gmail.com" },
          "value": "Comment gw nih 123"
        },
        {
          "user": { "fullName": "Flix", "email": "flixy121@gmail.com" },
          "value": "Comment gw nih 123",
          "created": "2024-01-20T12:04:08.394Z"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "id": "65abb2cbacb4458e1be4f18b"
}
```

I've tried using `populate` to achieve what i want like this

```
const result = await postModel
  .findById(req.params.postId)
  .populate('comments');
```

but i got an error

> Cannot populate path `comments` because it is not in your schema. Set the `strictPopulate` option to false to override.",

anyone can help me how to achieve what i want? i have create https://mongoplayground.net/p/VebB03fCqUR but i can't show the expected result since i don't really know how to play with `aggregate`

> I don't mind if a suggestion need to restructure my schema, since I'm still learning

Comment: here is aggregate if intetsred https://mongoplayground.net/p/BY3TOwU2gi8

Comment: @cmgchess the aggregate looks good, but i want to show detail of user in each comment also

Comment: Your data modelling is inverted. If you want to use `populate` and are in position to remodel I can provide a solution.

Comment: @jQueeny should i used ref in `Post` instead of `Comment`? I think it must be heavy when querying if i put any `ref` in `post`, that's why i used comment to reference `Post`

Comment: In `Post` I would have `comments: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Comment'}]`then you can have two-way populating depending on your query. This also allows deep populating because you will want to get `user` details from each comment i imagine.

Comment: @jQueeny Does it affect size of collection too much or it's still acceptable? I just read somewhere that MongoDB collection is limited to 16MB, the other question is when the `post` exceed the limit, what should i do? Create another collection called 'Post2`?

Comment: So you would only be storing the `ObjectId` of each `Comment` in each `Post` document. This is different from storing a subdocument in the document so it uses a very small amount of space. Yes 16MB is the document limitation so if you have millions of comments per post you may exceed that but unlikely.  I will write an example and you can ignore it if you don't like it.

Comment: I thought 16MB is size of collection not document, so I'll take a look at your suggestion then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give you a complete example of how to do this with mongoose `populate` you would need to update your `Post` schema like so:

```js
{
   //...
   author: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
      required: true, 
      ref: 'User'
  },
  description: String
  comments: [{ //< an array of comment _id
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
      required: true, 
      ref: 'Comment'
  }],
  //...
}
```

You need to push the `ObjectId` of each `Comment` document into the `Post.comments` array but I presume you already know that.

Since I'm here I would also change your `Comment` schema to this:

```js
{
   postId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
      required: true,
      ref: 'Post'
   },
   user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
      required: true,
      ref: 'User'
   },
   value: {
      type: String, 
      required: true
   },
   created: {
      type: Date, 
      default: Date.now //< pass the function not an invocation
   },
}
```

As you can see, remove the `comments` array from `Comment` schema. If a comment can have a comment then yes you will need an array but your current schema does not suggest that. As an aside, mongoose has [timestamps](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/timestamps.html) which are better than custom created at implementations.

Now when you want to populate:

```js
const result = await postModel.findById(req.params.postId)
.populate({
   path: 'comments', //< populate comments 
   populate: { path: 'user' } //< populate user of the recently populated comments
});
```

You can also get the `author`:

```js
const result = await postModel.findById(req.params.postId)
.populate('author')
.populate({
   path: 'comments', //< populate comments 
   populate: { path: 'user' } //< populate user of the recently populated comments
});
```

Comment: why i still need `Post` ref in `commentSchema`? is it just to help in case i need to populate `post` within `comment`?

Comment: @flix exactly. It makes querying your database more flexible and gives you more options. That question tells me you know what you're doing. Good luck with your project.